# I want to use v-lookup of excel in python

Tags: python

I have 3 excel sheet in three 3 different workbook. Now i want to read 2-3 columns of each sheet and want to combine into a single sheet.

basically i want to use v-lookup of excel in python.

Comment: I don't think python would be a good solution for this problem. Ideally you should first try to group the data into one sheet or a series of csv files and then attempt a manipulation with Python. For questions here you should have at least already started riting some code.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to import and merge datas from multiple file/sheets. then perform vlookup.

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet2')
merged = df1.merge(df2, on ='anycolname')
```

https://medium.com/importexcel/common-excel-task-in-python-vlookup-with-pandas-merge-c99d4e108988